# Access - VBA - Cannot import new excel file - but can after opening it once

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, import-from-excel

I'm using some VBA to import an excel file into Access.

```
Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, True, "A5:H5000"
End Sub
```

And:

```
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
Dim Item As Variant

Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
diag.Title = "Please select your excel file"
diag.Filters.Clear
diag.Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls, *.xlsx"

If diag.Show Then
    For Each Item In diag.SelectedItems
       Me.txtFileName = Item
    Next
End If


End Sub
```

The problem is as follows:

I extract an excel file from one of the applications we have running here. It's a 97-2003 .xls file.

If I do not open the file in excel first my access app will not import it, throwing a "table is in unexpected format"-error. If I open the excel file once in excel itself and close it (without altering or saving it) access will then accept the file.

I have other 97-2003 excel files exported from other applications which work fine without having to open them once...am at a loss here.

I've tried using acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8 and 9 instead. No luck.
The excel file is also not a .htm in disguise.

Does anyone here have any suggestions?

Comment: (a) After you "open the excel file once in excel itself and close it (without altering or saving it)" does the file's date/time last updated change when looking at the file using Windows Explorer?  (b) If you were to reboot your computer between opening it in Excel and trying to import it, does it still work or does it crash in the same way as not having opened it?

Comment: Ok I've tried both and here are the results:
a) when i open the excel file i can see in the explorer that its time stamp changes to the current date/time. However, when I close it the timestamp returns to creation date/time. I can import the file without problems afterwards.
b)I rebooted after opening the file in excel first and it will let me import the file without problems.

Hope that gives you an idea of what might be going on here.

Comment: I've swapped to using CSV and my app accepts those files without having to open first. 

So whilst my problem is 'solved' this issue still remains a mystery to me and if anyone has any ideas about what can cause this I'd gladly hear them.

Comment: Well my two theories about (a) a physical change being made to the file despite not saving it, or (b) some information being retained in memory that identifies the file, have both been proved unlikely.  So I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Can you export from Excel to Access using ADO???

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb;"
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "TableName", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable  
    ' all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can you do the same using DAO???

```
Sub DAOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, r As Long
    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb") 
    ' open the database
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable) 
    ' get all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can you import to Access form a closed Workbook???

```
GetDataFromClosedWorkbook "C:\FolderName\WorkbookName.xls", "A1:B21", ActiveCell, False
GetDataFromClosedWorkbook "C:\FolderName\WorkbookName.xls", "MyDataRange", Range ("B3"), True

Sub GetDataFromClosedWorkbook(SourceFile As String, SourceRange As String, _
    TargetRange As Range, IncludeFieldNames As Boolean)
' requires a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects library
' if SourceRange is a range reference:
'   this will return data from the first worksheet in SourceFile
' if SourceRange is a defined name reference:
'   this will return data from any worksheet in SourceFile
' SourceRange must include the range headers
'
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbConnectionString As String
Dim TargetCell As Range, i As Integer
    dbConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
        "ReadOnly=1;DBQ=" & SourceFile
    Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    On Error GoTo InvalidInput
    dbConnection.Open dbConnectionString ' open the database connection
    Set rs = dbConnection.Execute("[" & SourceRange & "]")
    Set TargetCell = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    If IncludeFieldNames Then
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            TargetCell.Offset(0, i).Formula = rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        Set TargetCell = TargetCell.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    TargetCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    dbConnection.Close ' close the database connection
    Set TargetCell = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set dbConnection = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
InvalidInput:
    MsgBox "The source file or source range is invalid!", _
        vbExclamation, "Get data from closed workbook"
End Sub
```

Finally...can you browse to an Excel file and import data from that file???

```
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim strTable As String, strBrowseMsg As String
Dim strFilter As String, strInitialDirectory As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

strBrowseMsg = "Select the EXCEL file:"

' Change C:\MyFolder\ to the path for the folder where the Browse
' window is to start (the initial directory). If you want to start in
' ACCESS' default folder, delete C:\MyFolder\ from the code line,
' leaving an empty string as the value being set as the initial
' directory
strInitialDirectory = "C:\MyFolder\"

strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Excel Files (*.xls)", "*.xls")

strPathFile = ahtCommonFileOpenSave(InitialDir:=strInitialDirectory, _
      Filter:=strFilter, OpenFile:=False, _
      DialogTitle:=strBrowseMsg, _
      Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)

If strPathFile = "" Then
      MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbOK, "No Selection"
      Exit Sub
End If

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
      strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
' Kill strPathFile
```

Try these examples and post back with your findings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions.

I'm right now checking if I can import the tables as csv file since I have that export option as well in my application. If that fails I'll check your methods and will report back.

Comment: I've swapped to using CSV and my app accepts those files without having to open first. 

So whilst my problem is 'solved' this issue still remains a mystery to me and if anyone has any ideas about what can cause this I'd gladly hear them.